# Error converting string to type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, json-serialization

I have an class which consist in which i have some problems filling a jsonElement from a json file as such

```
{
    "entities": [
        {
            "name": "DateTimeENT1",
            "description": "This a  example",
            "uil": {
                      "uill": "This is my Layout"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

which is being deserialized into this class:

```
public class Container {

    public ICollection<Entity> Entities {get; set;}
}


public class Entity {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Descripton {get; set;}
    UIL Uil {get; set;}
}

public class UIL{
    JsonElement Uill {get; set;}
}
```

and this is how I deserialize it:

```
var input= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container>(File.ReadAllText(@"init.json"));
```

when i run this I get an error stating that `'Error converting value "This is my Layout" to type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement'.`  how do I overcome this?

The weird part about all this is that I can use the same input on my controller endpoint

```
public IActionResult Put([FromBody] Container container)
```

which without any problem creates an container, with the given json.. 
so why does it not work when I do it with the deserializer?

Comment: I think `UIL` and `UIV` should be string instead of `JsonElement`?

Comment: I needs it to be an Some sort of Json which can be initialized by an string?

Comment: But the values like `"This is my Layout"` is just string, not JSON object.

Comment: @SelimYıldız I have an controller endpoint which receives this as an JSON and deserialize it without any problem to container class.. It seem to be a problem when I trigger this with an string

Comment: I have added an answer, please check.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use [`JsonDocument.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument.parse) instead of `JsonConverter.DeserializeObject`.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var jsonInput= @"{
                        ""entities"": 
                        [
                            {
                                ""name"": ""DateTimeENT1"",
                                ""description"": ""This a  example"",
                                ""uil"": {
                                        ""uill"": ""This is my Layout""
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }";

    using (JsonDocument doc = JsonDocument.Parse(jsonInput))
    {
        JsonElement root = doc.RootElement;
        JsonElement entities = root.GetProperty("entities");
        //Assuming you have only 1 item, if you have more you can use EnumerateArray and MoveNext()..
        JsonElement uilItem = entities[0].GetProperty("uil");
        JsonElement uillItem = uilItem.GetProperty("uill");
        Console.WriteLine(uillItem.GetString());
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output would be:

> This is my Layout

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting that your JSON is like the one you posted, you should change your `Entity` class and declare the property of `UIL` as string:

```
public class Container {

    public ICollection<Entity> Entities {get; set;}
}

public class Entity {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Descripton {get; set;}
    UIL Uil {get; set;}
}

public class UIL {
    public string Uill {get; set;}
}
```

`JsonElement` [is a struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement?view=netcore-3.1) and I don't know why you may want to map to this struct.

The endpoint is maybe working because it is not mapping that property as you want.

Comment: My controllers are able to do so - why am I not able to do so with the deserializer? @piraces

Comment: @howdoI I think the controller is not mapping this property... Can you check that?

Comment: checked it is though?

Comment: and `Uill` has the value of "This is my Layout"? That's weird... Nevertheless I think you should specify it is a string

Comment: UIl has `ValueKind = String : "This is my Layou2t"` or and yes I tries with a different string

Comment: Maybe the controller deserialization is done that way but the deserializer does the mapping in other way... Nevertheless, I think changing the property value to string is the best approach to make them both work, and then you don't have to access the property `ValueKind` to retrieve the `uill` value.